# MySQL Search Double with Currency Format

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP Based App that stores invoices entered by the user. Currently I have the invoice amount stored in a MySQL database tables as a `double` like so:

```
+------+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
| id   | date_entered | invoice_date | invoice_number | invoice_amount | client_type | unique_id | supplier_type | supplier_id | category_id | childcare_hours |
+------+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
|    1 | 1411098397   | 1411048800   | 123            |           0.01 |           0 |       137 |             0 |         139 |           5 |            NULL |
|    2 | 1412123404   | 1416920400   | 5093           |            130 |           0 |       168 |             0 |          19 |          18 |            NULL |
|    3 | 1412125933   | 1412085600   | 000            |             79 |           0 |       151 |             0 |         177 |           8 |            NULL |
|    4 | 1412645652   | 1412600400   | 000            |           60.8 |           0 |       104 |             0 |         179 |           9 |            NULL |
|    5 | 1412647563   | 1409320800   | 804560         |          225.5 |           0 |        18 |             0 |         174 |          10 |            NULL |
```

I am also using DataTables toorganise the data. I am using Server Side Processing to perform the data lookup to return as JSON.

The issue I am having is that the User is attempting to search by price eith by typing `$123` or `123.50` This is not working as the SQL is being genrated like so: `SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE invoice_amount LIKE "%$123%";`

This is obviosuly failing due to the data being stored in the database as a double.

My Question is, is there a way to make the SQL (or Maybe PHP) search for the correct value no matter what the client types in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any generic solution for the problem that you are facing but yeah you can remove the special characters like **$** etc. from the beginning or end of the invoice amount to be placed in the query. Moreover I'll recommend that you should use functions as **round** in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) as well as [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) in the best possible fashion rather than using the LIKE statement. Using LIKE statement is absolutely incorrect in this situation.

Comment: perhaps you are correct, maybe I should "sanitise" the query before I send it the the server (or once it is on the server)

Comment: You should remove "$" before executing the sql query.

Comment: This was my solution. Before I sent the search to the server I changed the value using javascript. Removed the `$` and used `parseFloat()` to make sure the number was a float

Answer (score 0):

You can try query without "$"

```
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE invoice_amount LIKE "%123%";
```

Comment: Thank you but the issues is that the user is entering in `$123` into the search box so the SSP is searching for what the user enters